# Woocommerce: add ACF field for product additional information

Tags: php, advanced-custom-fields

Good evening,

I tried to add an ACF field in the admin > ad product page, in order to add easier product additional information (under the default Woocommerce product specifications: weight, size).
I added the following code in the function.php child theme, but it didn't give result, and I've a message:

> Vos modifications de code PHP ont été annulées en raison d’une erreur
> sur la ligne 165 du fichier
> wp-content/themes/bookie-wp-child/functions.php. Veuillez la corriger
> et réessayer d’enregistrer.
> syntax error, unexpected token "<", expecting end of file

Can you help me? This is the code I tried to add. Thank you in advance.

````
<?php if ( $editeur ) : ?>
    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_term_link( $editeur ) ); ?>"><?php echo esc_html( $editeur->name ); ?></a>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php the_field( 'date_de_parution' ); ?>
<?php the_field( 'nombre_de_volumes' ); ?>
<?php the_field( 'nombre_de_pages' ); ?>
<?php the_field( 'isbn' ); ?>
<?php $presentation = get_field( 'presentation' ); ?>
<?php if ( $presentation ) : ?>
    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_term_link( $presentation ) ); ?>"><?php echo esc_html( $presentation->name ); ?></a>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php the_field( 'illustrateur' ); ?>```
````